# How can i find values after words in a string with python?

Tags: python, regex, string, extract, findall

My Problem:

I would like to read individual values ​​from a text file. The string that i load from the text file looks like this:

{'items': [{'id': '49656393', 'title': 'TOYOTA Priusplus', 'url': 'https://www.something.com', 'price': 24500, 'km': 30000, 'year': 2005}{'items': [{'id': '49656311', 'title': 'AUDI A3 Sportback', 'url': 'https://www.something2.com', 'price': 34500,'km': 14500, 'year': 2015}{'items': [{'id': '49656300', 'title': 'HYUNDAI 1.6', 'url': 'https://www.something3.com', 'price': 24500,'km': 10500, 'year': 2018}

It's important to know, that this is one string. I need the information in a excel/csv for every car. So i tried to extract the id, title, url, price, km and year for every record. But till yet it didn't work.

My code looks like this:

```
import re

with open(r'C:\Users\xy\Desktop\xyz\test.txt', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f:
    html_text = f.read()

find_id = re.findall(r"\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d", str(html_text))
find_title = re.findall(r"'title'\:.*\,", str(html_text))

print(find_id)
print(find_title)
```

With find_id i get the id, but find_title doesn't work. How i have change my code to find every id, title, url, price, km and year separated? I need the first value of the title, the second, the third and so on in a list. Like: ['TOYOTA Priusplus', 'AUDI A3 Sportback', 'HYUNDAI 1.6']. And the same with id, url, price, km and year. So i could take the lists and create a dataframe and a csv/excel file.

I would be very grateful for your help. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick with regex, try this:

```py
re.findall("'title'\:\s*\'(.+?)\'", str(html_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex for ID can fail if for example there will be an item where the 'km' or 'price' are also of the same length as ID because they both are just digits...
Also have a look at [json parsing with python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) because your data looks like json (except there are single quotes ' instead of double ").

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern to extract value: `(?<='KEY':\s)'?([^'},]+)`
replace the KEY with your desired id

```
import re

text = """
{'items': [{'id': '49656393', 'title': 'TOYOTA Priusplus', 'url': 'https://www.something.com', 'price': 24500, 'km': 30000, 'year': 2005}{'items': [{'id': '49656311', 'title': 'AUDI A3 Sportback', 'url': 'https://www.something2.com', 'price': 34500,'km': 14500, 'year': 2015}{'items': [{'id': '49656300', 'title': 'HYUNDAI 1.6', 'url': 'https://www.something3.com', 'price': 24500,'km': 10500, 'year': 2018}
"""

for key in ('id', 'title', 'url', 'price', 'km', 'year'):
    print(re.findall(f"(?<='{key}':\s)'?([^'}},]+)", text))
```

Output:

```
['49656393', '49656311', '49656300']
['TOYOTA Priusplus', 'AUDI A3 Sportback', 'HYUNDAI 1.6']
['https://www.something.com', 'https://www.something2.com', 'https://www.something3.com']
['24500', '34500', '24500']
['30000', '14500', '10500']
['2005', '2015', '2018']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following approach:

1. 1st it splits the entire string into segment list by this regex :
   `r"}?{'items':"`
2. Then apply this regex `f"'{index}'\s*:\s*('[^']+'|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"`
   to get key value pair
3. Then put all the keys into a dictionary `dic`
4. Then put the dictionary into a list `finalResults`
5. So finally you have full result set in a list of dictionary

You May try that: ([Run here](https://ideone.com/LTKiyo) )

```
import re

regex = r"}?{'items':"

s = "{'items': [{'id': '49656393', 'title': 'TOYOTA Priusplus', 'url': 'https://www.something.com', 'price': 24500, 'km': 30000, 'year': 2005}{'items': [{'id': '49656311', 'title': 'AUDI A3 Sportback', 'url': 'https://www.something2.com', 'price': 34500,'km': 14500, 'year': 2015}{'items': [{'id': '49656300', 'title': 'HYUNDAI 1.6', 'url': 'https://www.something3.com', 'price': 24500,'km': 10500, 'year': 2018}"

segments=re.compile("}?{'items':").split(s)



finalResult=[];
for l in segments:
    if(len(l)>0):
        dic={}
        for index in ('id', 'title', 'url', 'price', 'km', 'year'):
            value = re.search(f"'{index}'\s*:\s*('[^']+'|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)",l);
            dic[index]=value.group(1);
        finalResult.append(dic);

## you have the complete result in finalResult
## The following codes just prints the result as I desire
    
cnt=0;
for records in finalResult:
    cnt=cnt+1
    print(cnt)
    print('id='+records['id'])
    print('title='+records['title'])
    print('url='+records['url'])
    print('km='+records['km'])  
    print('year='+records['year'])
```